# home page component doesn't appear correctly

Tags: visualforce-component

I have one VF page that wanted to be inserted to Home Page. The setting in Production and Sandbox is the same.

Strange thing is in Sandbox, even I set up the same thing as in Production, the VF page layout doesn't appear correctly. I can only see little bit of VF page.

Here is the setting of VF in the Home Component.

```
<iframe src="/apex/VF_MyPage" frameborder="no" height="10px" id="000000111111" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="000000111111" scrolling="no" title="VF_MyPage" width="100%"></iframe>&nbsp;<style type="text/css">h2 {display:none !important;}</style>
```

Can anyone give me useful hints?

Comment: Should the height of the iframe be 10px?

Comment: Hi, funny thing is height = '10px' in Production too. It is showing correctly. However, I will just change the height of sandbox first. But quite feel confused. I just wonder why it is behaving differently in Production. I accept when I change to height= '300px', seem quite look good in Sandbox. But how come in Production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe src="/apex/VF_MyPage" frameborder="no" height="250px" id="000000111111" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="000000111111" scrolling="no" title="VF_MyPage" width="100%"></iframe>&nbsp;<style type="text/css">h2 {display:none !important;}</style>
```

I just increase the height. But as in the production, although setting as 10px is working fine. I felt quite weird.